# Dynamically update cart totals using JS and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, events

I'm making a simple cart page for a website and wanted to have cart totals update dynamically. For some reason nothing adjusts though. I also don't receive an error or any activity in the console which makes me wonder if I'm using class names improperly. It's been a long time since I've tried this so apologies for forgetting how haha. Here is my html:

```
<tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="cart-info">
                        <img src="images/watercolor2.jpg">
                        <div>
                            <p>Watercolor Set</p>
                            
                            <div class="price" data-amount="25.00">Price: $25.00</div><br>
                            <a href="">Remove</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td><input class="quantity" type="number" value="0"></td>
                <td class="total">$0.00</td>
            </tr>
```

and js:

var quantity = document.getElementsByClassName("quantity");

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(quantity, update);

function update(val, i){
  val.addEventListener('input', function(){
    var x = val.value;
    document.getElementsByClassName('total')[i].innerHTML = "$" +
      (x*document.getElementsByClassName('price')[i].getAttribute("data-amount")).toFixed(2);
  });
};
```

I've double checked the script src is spelled properly and is posted above the  tag in the html file...what am I overlooking? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd approach it. Use `querySelectorAll` in concert with `closest()`, applying the function through an `input` event listener. Also, you can access the `data-amount` via the `dataset` property

```js
const doGrandTotal = () => {
  let gtotal = 0;
  document.querySelectorAll('.total').forEach(t => {
    gtotal += +t.innerText.replaceAll("$", "")
  })
  document.querySelector('#gtotal').innerText = `$${gtotal.toFixed(2)}`;
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.quantity').forEach(q => {
    q.addEventListener('input', e => {
      let p = +e.target.closest('tr').querySelector('[data-amount]').dataset.amount * +e.target.value;
      e.target.closest('tr').querySelector('.total').innerText = `$${p.toFixed(2)}`;
      doGrandTotal()
    })
  })
  doGrandTotal()
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="cart-info">
        <img src="images/watercolor2.jpg">
        <div>
          <p>Watercolor Set</p>

          <div class="price" data-amount="25.00">Price: $25.00</div><br>
          <a href="">Remove</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td><input class="quantity" type="number" value="0"></td>
    <td class="total">$0.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="cart-info">
        <img src="images/watercolor2.jpg">
        <div>
          <p>Watercolor Set</p>

          <div class="price" data-amount="25.00">Price: $25.00</div><br>
          <a href="">Remove</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td><input class="quantity" type="number" value="0"></td>
    <td class="total">$0.00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr> Grand total: <span id='gtotal'></span>
```

Comment: Oh this is great, thank you ! What would be the best way to sum all of the totals at as a subtotal?

Comment: I added a function for that at the end. It runs when the page loads so there can be a $0.00 to start.

Comment: @AstralV - was this helpful? If so, consider marking it as the solution (clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer) and/or upvoting. It's the best way of expressing gratitude on this site when someone helps.